# Volley Post GSON Request Issue

Tags: android, serialization, android-volley, android-networking

I have created the volley custom post GSon request, but i am unable to call it.

**GSON POST Request:**

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    private final Map<String, String> params;
    private final Response.Listener<T> listener;

    /**
     * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
     *
     * @param url URL of the request to make
     * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
     * @param headers Map of request headers
     */
    public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
                       Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.params = null;
    }

    /**
     * Make a POST request and return a parsed object from JSON.
     *
     * @param url URL of the request to make
     * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
     */
    public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> params,
                       Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.params = params;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.headers = null;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json = new String(
                    response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(
                    gson.fromJson(json, clazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

}
```

**Response Generic Model Classes: **

```
public class BaseResponse<T> implements Serializable {

    private boolean response;

    private String message;

    private String status;

    private String userStatus;
    private String token;

    private T data;

    public boolean isResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(boolean response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getUserStatus() {
        return userStatus;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
}
```

**Data Model Class:**

```
 public class OTPCode  implements Serializable {

        private String code;
    @SerializedName("mobile")
        private String phone;
 @SerializedName("id")
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private String email;


        public String getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(String userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }
    }
```

**Below is Callback which showing error :**

```
GsonRequest<BaseResponse<OTPCode>> baseResponseGsonRequest = new GsonRequest<BaseResponse<OTPCode>>
                (Request.Method.POST,url,BaseResponse<OTPCode>.class, params, new Response.Listener<BaseResponse<OTPCode>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(BaseResponse<OTPCode> response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
```

> I am parsing BaseResponse.class to GsonRequest but its
>   showing me error. I might doing some mistake. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

As BaseResponse is generic class, .class will not work, use Type for that

Type baseResponseType=new TypeToken<>(){}.getType();